# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml' on venv Centos

Tags: python, xpath, virtualenv, lxml, libxml2

im just trying to run a script to extract some data from a xml using XPATH, so i read i should use lxml or libxml2. The problem is i cant import any of this libraries in any case i get the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named" and the name of the module im trying to import.

I am running my script on a virtual environment with Python 2.7.13, i already execute the pip install instruction for both libraries, and i get that message that both of them are already installed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @DarkDiamonD Centos

Comment: Please show a log of exactly what you're doing